# Stripe Checkout Session for Subscription, error on webhook

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am creating a stripe checkout session for my subscription based product price like this.

```
$request->user()->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
$array = [
    'customer' => $request->user()->stripe_id,
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'line_items' => [[
        'price' => $plan->stripe_plan,
        'quantity' => 1,
    ]],
    'mode' => 'subscription',
    'success_url' => route('success'),
    'cancel_url' => route('cancel'),
];
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_KEY');
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create($array);
```

On the view, I am redirecting user to the checkout page, like this:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_KEY');
stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: '{{$session->id}}'}).then(function (result) {});
</script>
```

Everything is working smoothly, except webhook isn't being registered, it throws an error:

```
Undefined index: name
Level
ERROR
Exception
{
    "class": "ErrorException",
    "message": "Undefined index: name",
    "code": 0,
    "file": "/home/adm/public_html/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Http/Controllers/WebhookController.php:79",
    "trace": [
        "/home/adm/public_html/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Http/Controllers/WebhookController.php:79",
        "/home/adm/public_html/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Http/Controllers/WebhookController.php:48",
        "/home/adm/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54",
        "/home/adm/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:45",
```

I looked up `WebhookController.php:79` and there's basically nothing calling upon the index `name`. Here's an snippet from `WebhookController.php`:

```
protected function handleCustomerSubscriptionUpdated(array $payload)
{
    if ($user = $this->getUserByStripeId($payload['data']['object']['customer'])) {
        $data = $payload['data']['object'];

        $user->subscriptions->filter(function (Subscription $subscription) use ($data) {
            return $subscription->stripe_id === $data['id'];
        })->each(function (Subscription $subscription) use ($data) {
            if (
                isset($data['status']) &&
                $data['status'] === StripeSubscription::STATUS_INCOMPLETE_EXPIRED
            ) {
                $subscription->items()->delete();
                $subscription->delete();

                return;
            }

            // Plan...
            $subscription->stripe_plan = $data['plan']['id'] ?? null;

            // Quantity...
            $subscription->quantity = $data['quantity'];

            // Trial ending date...
            if (isset($data['trial_end'])) {
                $trialEnd = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($data['trial_end']);

                if (! $subscription->trial_ends_at || $subscription->trial_ends_at->ne($trialEnd)) {
                    $subscription->trial_ends_at = $trialEnd;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I am thinking this is happening because, I have no involvement of Laravel Cashier whatsoever when creating the checkout session, however, there's an involvement when receiving the webhook

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you didn't use Laravel Cashier to create the Checkout Session and the Laravel webhook controller expects values that you didn't provide. Specifically, Cashier expects a `name` property in the Session's [metadata](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/12.x/src/Http/Controllers/WebhookController.php#L82).

Since you have no metadata at all, that line is failing.

You should either look into creating the Checkout Session with Cashier, or [write your own webhook handler code](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/integration-builder) and don't use Cashier at all.